# What does the "@" in ASP MVC mean/do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know this is a simple question, but I am new to ASP MVC and just can't find the answer to this anywhere - what is the "@" that I am seeing everywhere? example:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
}

<h2>Welcome</h2>

<ul> 
   @for (int i=0; i < ViewBag.NumTimes; i++) { 
      <li>@ViewBag.Message</li> 
   } 
</ul>
```

Comment: it is the code block marker for the razor engine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ is a syntax element of Razor engine, that is used in ASP.NET MVC 3. 
Your code will show text from `ViewBag.Message` `ViewBag.NumTimes` times.

ViewBag properties are dynamic and can be populated from controller.

Take a look http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx to the Razor syntax

Answer (score 3):

It's the symbol that "toggles" between code and HTML so to speak. For Webforms, the <% %> syntax is used. Whenever the server encounters the symbol, it will execute the code (C# in your case), and replace it with HTML. If you've ever used PHP it's equal to the

```
 <?php ?>
```

tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of the syntax for the Razor view engine. You should find answers by including this in your search terms. From the [Razor page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor.aspx):

> ‘@’ is the magic character that precedes code instructions