# Asp.Net Mvc Razor Model with @ and with @

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two code which are giving the same output. what would be the difference here if I use 
Model.ItemPrice and @Model.ItemPrice? both give same result.

```
@if(Model.ItemPrice == "1300")
{
   @Model.ItemPrice   
}

@if(@Model.ItemPrice == "1300")
{
 @Model.ItemPrice   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference between using `Model` and `@Model` in your `@if(...)` statement.

`@` starts a code section *or* outputs a variable in Razor syntax, and once in code (so in your `@if(...)`), it is a character to escape reserved words as defined in the C# syntax.

For the former see [What does the “@” in ASP MVC mean/do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310940/what-does-the-in-asp-mvc-mean-do), the latter is explained in [What's the use/meaning of the @ character in variable names in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

none. the @ is only used as an escape to put Razor code in the view.