# Why does Html.DisplayFor work when not in an IF statement?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this bit of code in my MVC view:

```
<div style="">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContentResourceFile.FileName)
    @if (item.ContentResourceFile != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ContentResourceFile.FileName))
    {
        Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContentResourceFile.FileName);
    }
</div>
```

The first DisplayFor of FileName works it renders out in the results, but the one in the IF statement does not render out.

Can somebody explain why?

Comment: after you add `@` to the second `Html.DisplayFor`... make sure you delete the `;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example, `Html.DisplayFor(...)` is prefixed by `@` which tells the Razor view engine to render the result as HTML. In the second example, you're calling the same function, but doing nothing with the result. (Imagine what output you'd get if you said `Math.Sqrt(4)` instead... nothing).

What you probably wanted was to force the Razor view engine to render your result by switching back into "HTML" context - perhaps like this:

```
{
    <text>@Html.DisplayFor(...)</text>
}
```

`<text>` is a special pseudo-tag recognized by the Razor view engine, and doesn't appear in the output HTML.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're missing an `@` before the second `Html.DisplayFor()`. In this context, `@` instructs Razor to output the result of the following expression to the output.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310940/what-does-the-in-asp-mvc-mean-do
Wouldn't the whole IF statement be wrapped in it's `@`?

Comment: No, the `@` before the `if` indicates that a code block follows. You need another `@` for `Html.DisplayFor()` to indicate that it should be output.

Comment: So, the first `@` puts me in code mode, the second `@` before my `Html.DisplayFor` puts me back in 'render this' mode? Sorry if I sound juvenile, I just really want to understand this instead of just copying code from Bing.

Comment: No problem, but yes, that's it. See row 1 and 2 in the table at [C# Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/).